2 date filters above a table
I am designing a screen that has a table of campaigns. above the table, some filters are always visible.
one filter is by creation date, and 2nd is by modification date. the problem is that our date pickers has the label inside them and when selected it shows date. so user will see 2 dates inside date pickers?

do you have a screenshot to help us visualize the issue?

Adding static text labels above or next to input fields allows users to always read and understand what the data in the input fields refers to, even when typing in the input field.


From what I understand, you have date input fields with internal labels that disappear when a date is entered.
Since there are two date fields that must contain values for specific things, it's even more important to show the user what each field is for. In other words, having a label is very essential as it facilitates understanding.
To maintain this internal label dynamic, you can use the design and usability format from https://m3.material.io/ as an example.
I hope this helps. Sorry for the English.



You don't need individual labels for the two date fields if you have a label for them both, like "Date range" or something like that.
Here is an example (in Swedish):

